# why is my image slider not working?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image-gallery

I am creating an image slider but the slider is showing always the same image.

this is the Jquery code I made

```
$(document).ready(function(){

slide();

});
var next = 1;
var num = $('#slider img').size();
function slide(){

$('.'+next).show("slide",{direction:"right"},500);
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.'+next).hide("slide",{direction:"left"},500);
    slide();
    if(next == num){
        next = 1;
    }else{
        next = next+1;
    }

},2000);

}
```

and this the slider html

```
<div id="slider">
    <img  class="1" src="img/1.jpg"  alt="1">
    <img  class="2" src="img/2.jpg"  alt="2">
    <img  class="3" src="img/3.jpg"  alt="3">
</div>
```

See [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6yoxta2z/)

Can somebody help to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just adjusted your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6yoxta2z/1/)

with the adjustment

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('.' + next).hide("slide", {
        direction: "left"
    }, 500);

    if (next == num) {
        next = 1;
    } else {
        next +=  1;
    }
    return slide(next);
}, 2000);
```

instead of

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('.' + next).hide("slide", {
        direction: "left"
    }, 500);
    slide();
    if (next == num) {
        next = 1;
    } else {
        next +=  1;
    }
 }, 2000);
```

so the `slide()` will be called with the next image.